# Asp.net MVC 4 Load view renderer at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I achieve this in MVC 4?

I have a list of animals like below.

**Name      domestic**
Cat           yes              view
Dog          yes              view
Tiger        no                view

Clicking on **view** will render bio info of respective animal. I have to configure different views for each animals. I will have a database table where renderer is configured against each animal like below

**Animal type      Renderer Type**
Cat                     CatRenderer
Dog                    DogRenderer
Tiger                  TigerRenderer

Should I use

- Different controller as different renderer types, or
- Different partial views as different renderer types

Note: I don’t want to use Switch-case statement.

Renderer will inherit from base type (AnimalRenderer : IAnimalRenderer).

Comment: Why do you need different views for each animal?

Comment: Do you have base `class Animal` and then inherited `class Dog`, `class Cat` etc?

Comment: I would usually create a view model for each animal in the controller. You could use this approach and let the controller assign a partial view name to each animal type. (or let the interface define the view name but this would break the separation between model and view logic)

Comment: Robert, I need different views as HTML for each view is going to be very different.

Comment: Stephen, that is true, base class will be Animal and inherited classes Dog, Cat etc.... I have to decide renderer at runtime based on user selection, If user selects dog, a database query will find out what renderer I need to load based on type. Hope I have explained my situation well.

Comment: I don't see why you need anything in your database relating to a 'Renderer' (and its bad practice as it breaks the separation between model and view logic).  You can either create templates for each class or return different partial views. PS. to respond to a comment, start the message with @Stephen (or whoever your responding to) so we get notified.